# Low coolant level and high engine oil in VW

Tags: oil, vw, coolant, coolant-leak

I have a 1.5-year-old (mileage ~7000km) [Volkswagen Vento](https://www.volkswagen.co.in/en/models/vento.html) with 1.6 MPI Petrol engine. Recently I noticed that my coolant level was below minimum and my engine oil level was higher than the max on the dipstick. I went to the authorised Volkswagen service centre in my city to get the car inspected. As per them, it is normal for the coolant to get consumed with usage and higher than max engine oil level does not cause any harm to the engine. When I got the car serviced around 6 months back from the same service centre, I was told that Volkswagen uses lifelong coolant (G-13) which doesn't need replacement for 4-5 years (or 40k km). Now they are contradicting themselves saying that coolant is consumed with use and they just topped it up back to normal.

It would be really great if someone can advise me if it's fine to use the car with a high level of engine oil and if the coolant level can reduce on its own without some kind of leakage.

EDIT - Following is an image of the dipstick with current oil level
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those answers surprises me coming from an authorized service center. Running with oil above maximum is not alright, there's usually a small margin of error given by the manufacturer on the "Max" indication of the dipstick, but it should still be respected. Excessive oil can damage the engine.

Also, the coolant level shouldn't go down unless you have a leak on your cooling system, specially with the mileage you stated. The leak could be something more complicated, like a hole in the radiator, or something simpler to resolve, like a bad hose clamp, but it should anyways get checked. On an authorized center they should have a pressure tester that can confirm the presence of leaks in a relatively short time.

After confirmation they would still need to check for the source of the leak, which could take longer depending on where it is and how big it is.

[image: Cooling System Pressure Tester]

Their answer sounds like the answer of someone trying to dodge the trouble of actually working on the car..

Comment: When I asked them to inspect, the best they did was to look in the engine compartment with a flashlight (phone's flash) and within 30 seconds they concluded that there was no leak. Considering my warranty will expire in 3 months, I should get back to them.

Comment: @VivekKumar I'd be inclined to go to a different dealer.. This lot sounds to be somewhere between incompetent and lazy

Answer (score 1):

Yes-back to them for warranty and INSIST they sort it-coolant is a sealed system and should not reduce. You can lose oil, but if you are GAINING oil and losing ccoolant, i would suggest they are linked and this-is serious-